# Why am I getting an unchecked warning here?

Tags: java, generics

Dataset extends ArrayList.

```
Dataset<Pair<SRGB>> data = new Dataset<Pair<SRGB>>();
Statement stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
    data.add(new Pair<SRGB>(SRGB.create(rs.getString(2)),
                            SRGB.create(rs.getString(3)),
                            rs.getDouble(1),
                            rs.getInt(4)));
}
warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.ArrayList
```

Comment: Which line causes the warning?

Comment: does Dataset override the add(<T> element) function of ArrayList?

Comment: Please show how you are declaring the `Dataset` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chances are you've declared your `Dataset` class to extend `ArrayList` without any generic type.

Make sure your `Dataset` class extends `ArrayList` like so:

```
class Dataset<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    // ...
}
```

And **not**

```
class Dataset<T> extends ArrayList {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just to elaborate on this (already good!) answer a bit: when you declare `class Dataset<T> extends ArrayList`, you are declaring a new type variable that has nothing to do with the element type variable of the `ArrayList`. Using the same type variable in both places is what establishes the link.

Comment: yeah, it's pretty apparent once you think about it.  i'm just new to java, so i haven't come across this before.

Answer (score -1):

maybe [this](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) documentation will help you

I know this was not your question but did you know that you can suppress these warnings with an annotation :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

Comment: the documentation was not relevant.  i'm not casting and i'm not using raw types.  yes, i did know that.